# How do I change light bulb in flush mounted fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, removal

I just moved into a new house and don't know how to change this flush mounted light:

[image: Img]

I've tried removing the piece at the bottom and that didn't drop the light as I would have expected. The other lights in the house seem to be Murray Feiss lights and the closest one I could find isn't the same.

The glass seems to extend up into the metal ring at the top and I am unable to rotate the glass separate from the ring. There appears to be some insulation or foam above the metal ring.

I have tried rotating the whole thing (it moves but doesn't loosen), prying at the top ring (it appears there is a screw that goes down from the ceiling plate that seems to be holding it up, but that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the previous owner had 3 100 watt bulbs in a fixture only rated for 60 watt bulbs. This caused the paint on the metal to peel/adhere to the glass. It eventually fell off on its own since I left the bottom screw off.

One of the sockets was blackened from the heat, so all 3 of these things in my house are getting replaced ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is similar to [this one](http://www.feiss.com/InstructionSheets/FM324.pdf). The finial on the bottom should unscrew and allow the glass to drop.  It's possible that you'll find a nut inside someplace (or that some part of the finial trim is just stuck).  I have occasionally run into fixtures where the threaded pipe is one piece that goes all the way through from finial to mounting bar, but if you keep turning the finial anti-clockwise it should eventually separate someplace.